# Make selection of plotly appear in a datatable - flexdashboard

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, flexdashboard, crosstalk

I am trying to build a flexdashbaord with two columns, The first one is a simple plot_ly scatter plot. In the second column I want a DT data table that will show the data of the points selected via box or lasso select in the scatter plot as shown in the screenshot below.

[image: problem screenshot]

Code below:

````
```{r global, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(reticulate)
library(tidyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(purrr) 
library(DT)
library(shinyalert)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(thematic)
library(dashboardthemes)
library(shinyjs)
library(datasets)
library(crosstalk)


data(iris)
summary(iris)

```


```{r runandsavereactive}

#run and generate data
actionButton("run_button", "RUN")

```

### create plot
```{r update_data}
output_data <- eventReactive(input$run_button, {

    showModal(modalDialog(title = "Running!"))
  
  
    ## Start initial plot
  fig2 <- iris %>% 
    plot_ly(
      type = 'scatter',
      mode = 'markers',
      x = ~Sepal.Length,
      y = ~Petal.Length,
      #marker = list(size = ~numbEmployed, sizeref = 4000, sizemode = 'area'),
      color = ~Species,
      marker = list(size = 5),
      hoverinfo = 'text',
      text = ~paste0("Name: ",Species),
      source="A"
    ) 


  ## style the layout
  fig2 <- fig2 %>% 
    layout(
      title = 'iris data test',
      scene = list(
        xaxis = list(title = ' ',
                     range = list(-4,7),
                     showticklabels=FALSE,
                     zeroline = F,
                     showgrid = F
        ),
        yaxis = list(title = ' ',
                     range = list(-1, 5),
                     showticklabels=FALSE,
                     zeroline = F,
                     showgrid = F
        )
     
      ))
   
  list("fig2" = fig2)
})
```


### Scatter Plot
```{r data }

plotlyOutput("iris")

output$iris <- renderPlotly({
req(input$run_button)
req(output_data()$fig2)

output_data()$fig2 

})

```



### Data Table

```{r datatsble }

output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(data)
proxy <- DT::dataTableProxy("table")
observe({
... 
})
```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not really provide a [reprex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), so I show some toy example of how to solve this issue (no need for shiny):

````
---
title: "Crosstalk"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(plotly)
library(crosstalk)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)
```

```{r crosstalk-setup}
## Add an id to not rely only on rownumbers
my_iris <- iris %>% 
  mutate(id = paste("id", 1:n()))
shared_iris <- SharedData$new(my_iris, key = ~ id)
```


## Row

### Plot

```{r plot}
shared_iris %>% 
  plot_ly(
    type = "scatter",
    mode = "markers",
    x = ~ Sepal.Length,
    y = ~ Petal.Length,
    color = ~ Species,
    marker = list(size = 5),
    hoverinfo = "text",
    text = ~ id
  ) %>%
  ## Tell plotly do highlight on selection rather on click
  highlight(on = "plotly_selected",
            off = "plotly_deselect")
```


### Table

```{r}
datatable(shared_iris)
```
````

All you need is `crosstalk`. You create a `SharedData` object (I decided to use an explicit `id` column instead of relying on row numbers which can be fragile in some scenarios) and pass this to both `plotly` and `datatable`. Finaly, you just need to use `highlight` to change the default behaviour of `plotly` to select on rectangular / lasso brush instead of click.

[image: Picture showing that the selected points are now shown in the table]

Comment: Works a treat- thank you!